# Fakerjs unsafe assignment of an any value

Tags: typescript, faker.js

Does anyone know why I'm getting the following error when trying to populate an array that I've typed?

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
Unsafe member access .lorem on an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
```

My code is:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import {faker} from '@faker-js/faker'

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

enum Priority {
    HIGH = 'HIGH',
    MEDIUM = 'MEDIUM',
    LOW = 'LOW'
}

interface Deadline {
    title: string;
    description?:string;
    date: Date;
}   

const deadlines: Deadline[] = Array.from({length:100}, () => ({
    title: faker.lorem.sentences({min: 10, max: 20}),
    description: faker.lorem.sentences({min: 3, max: 30}),
    date: faker.date.future({years: 1})
}))
```

Comment: Can you clarify at what lines do each error appear?

Comment: Each prop gets the same error

Comment: @Mathew were you able to solve this?
I'm having the same issue.

not sure if it's helpful, but these are the packages I'm using.


"@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
"@types/faker": "^6.6.9",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
"typescript": "^3.9.5",